# Credential should be scoped to a valid region when creating AWS-chime meeting

Tags: aws-serverless, aws-chime-sdk

```
            let meetingId = null;
            let meeting = null;
            let clientId = 2017;
            meetingId = uuid();
            var region = await getNearestMediaRegion();
            const chime = new AWS.Chime({ region: region });
            chime.endpoint = new AWS.Endpoint('https://service.chime.aws.amazon.com');
            meeting = await chime.createMeeting({
                ClientRequestToken: meetingId,
                MediaRegion: region,
                ExternalMeetingId: meetingId,
            }).promise();
            const attendee = await chime.createAttendee({
                    MeetingId: meeting.Meeting.MeetingId,
                    ExternalUserId: `${uuid().substring(0, 8)}#${clientId}`,
                })
                .promise();
            let res = { meeting, attendee };
```

I've created meeting using Amazon chime SDK in Serverless refer following example

[example](https://www.sufle.io/blog/serverless-meetings-with-amazon-chime-sdk)

OUTPUT:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove following line from your code:

```
chime.endpoint = new AWS.Endpoint('https://service.chime.aws.amazon.com');
```